# XPath select node that don't have specified child

Tags: xml, xpath, nodes

```
<a>
   <b />
   <c />
</a>
<a1>
   <b />
</a1>
```

How can I select nodes, that don't have specified child node? For example I need all node, that doesn't have **c** node, in my example **a1**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b />
        <c />
    </a>
    <a1>
        <b />
    </a1>
</root>
```

Use: `/root/*[not(c)]`

The result is `a1`.

Comment: I think, you can suggest **XPATH** as `/*/*[not(c)]`